If "Good luck finding a new job" is sarcastic, how do I change the sentence to make it sound well-intentioned?
I have read on many websites that Good luck finding a new job is sarcastic and not a well-intentioned wish.
How do I make it well-intentioned and still use finding?

"Good luck finding a new job" can be sarcastic, e.g. if said to a colleague who is planning to do something foolish that may put them in bad standing with the management, or result in dismissal; it is not sarcastic if said to a colleague who has announced that they are leaving to seek a new job. The situation and tone of voice make the intended meaning clear.

I’m voting to close this question because whether "Good luck with that!" is sarcastic or sincere is nothing to do with changing the actual words. It's a matter of context and delivery.

I just enjoyed watching the new movie Inside Out 2. At one point, the adolescent brain discovers the use of sarcasm, depicted visually as a "Sarc Chasm," a great canyon. Characters shout messages to other characters on the other side of the divide, and their well-intentioned meanings come out inverted by a sarcastic tone. While written language has "tone," it creates it through context and leading clues. If you are giving little context, you have little control to steer the tone.

I'd avoid it and use a different construction instead.

No, I've never seen it used in sarcastic way.

Not sure about keeping the word ''find'' in this context, but could say ''I hope the job search goes well'' or something like that.

Sarcasm in English comes from tone not from an expression per se. An expression like this one.

"I have read on many websites that ..."  web sites are garbage.  Only here on ELL can you trust information!  The sentence is NOT sarcastic.  (Of course, any sentence in English can be used sarcastically. Sarcasm is extremely common in English.)

The OP asks a completely legitimate question and specifies American idioms.  If you haven't lived in the US or Canada for a significant period of time (decades,) are you sure you are helping by gaslighting them about this?

@MichaelHarvey In the UK one might say "That is a brave decision" instead.

Is mentioning British usage 'gaslighting'?

Sarcasm is a fickle an oftenly subtle thing. If and how it's interpreted is also culture-bound. Your phrase is certainly not always used sarcastically.

I don't think 'Good luck finding a new job' is necessarily sarcastic and not a well-intentioned wish.
As @Michael Harvey rightly said.  It depends on the situation and our tone.
Some interpretations may just be taking this informal definition of "good luck" with no bad intention.

2 informal → used to say that one thinks what someone is trying to do is difficult or impossible

Sense 1 of this dictionary says

1 → used to say that one hopes someone will succeed

How your message will be interpreted has nothing to do with the gerund-participle finding.
I believe if we convey our goodwill sincerely, the listener would not misunderstand.
Edit
I prefer Good luck with your job search which has many more hits.  Good luck with finding a new job is fine too.

Thank you. And I can say Good luck with finding a new job too? That's equally correct and natural, right?

The point is that "Good luck!" can be sincere or sarcastic regardless of what you are wishing the person luck with.

@Idunno, I have added to my answer my response to your additional query.

What I like about this answer is that, while it's true that the phrase isn't always or automatically sarcastic, there are patterns that sarcastic uses stick to, like "Good luck with that." Disrupting the pattern just a little should avoid the danger of being misunderstood, like "Wishing you good luck finding a new job!" Personally, I'd go with "I hope your job search goes well!"

@AndyBonner - best of luck prising the gin bottle out of Mother's hands - sarcastic or sincere?

@MichaelHarvey sincere wishing of good luck, whilst expressing skepticism about the achievability of the task.

@Idunno please note THAT IT IS RUDE TO WISH SOMEONE LUCK FINDING A JOB.  Don't do it.  Of course they can find a new job, they don't need luck.

@Fattie - there's a tale going the rounds that a reference for a candidate for a job contained this gem 'If you get this person to work for you, you will be very lucky'.

@Fattie, I've never heard this before and it sounds nuts--there's a huge element of luck in job hunting!

Can you please explain what basis you have for this assertion about AmE?

@MichaelHarvey that recommendation is rather like "This person will work to the best of their ability".

@WeatherVane - but it also can mean 'you will have a hard time getting this person to do any work'.

@MichaelHarvey and mine implies that their ability is not great.

Context is Everything.
"Good luck finding a new job" can indeed be read as sarcastic. By itself, that's probably how it will be read.
"I was so happy to work with you. You taught me more than anyone else and I was devastated to learn you were leaving. Thank you for everything. Good luck finding a new job!" ...will generally read as sincere, unless the first part is blatantly false.
If you are concerned about coming across as sarcastic, add a little bit more language to indicate that you are sincere.

I'm going to disagree with most of the answers here.  It's hard to imagine a context where "good luck finding a new job" doesn't have a negative tinge to it. There's something idiomatic about this phrase, at least to me.  If could be where I am from, my age group, or something like that. I would never say that to someone. There's too much risk it will be taken as a 'dig'.
I don't know how to explain it exactly, but if you say:

Good luck finding your next job/role

It feels unambiguously supportive.  I think it's the implicit assertion that the subject will find a new job.

Here is a context: a colleague of mine has already given formal notice they will leave the company, though they haven't found a new job yet.

@DocBrown And in that context, it could be interpreted that they have maybe made a mistake.  I think part of the issue is there's a cultural assumption that luck is in opposition to skill or talent. The implication that luck is needed is a bit of a slight. It's not completely logical. Wishing someone luck on an exam is totally fine.

Frame challenge:  "...finding a new job" is the problem. I'd replace with "Best wishes for your future". I'd also avoid email is at all possible, as your way of speaking says more: sound sincere.

Or other similar wording such as, "Good luck with your job search" / "job hunting".

This answer is unclear. Why is it a problem to say "...finding a new job"?

@kaya3 If the speaker (1) thinks the other person will be fired, and (2) that other people won't want to hire them, and (3) wants to convey this to the other person in a hurtful manner, then there is no problem at all.

You've written that your answer is a frame challenge, but I don't see how this answer challenges anything in the question. And your comment seems to say, in fact, that you agree with OP's assessment of the original wording. So what is it about the original wording which conveys sarcasm, and how does your proposed alternative avoid the problem? And if the words "good luck" aren't the problem, why is it necessary to change them to "best wishes"?

@kaya3 "what is it about the original wording which conveys sarcasm,..." There is your problem: the words don't convey sarcasm, but they are open to a sarcastic interpretation. Sarcasm is often a matter of tone, and convention. I suggested changing the words to make that interpretation less likely.

The other answers at this point in time1 have largely not addressed the formal requirement of keeping2 the gerund "finding". So, to that end:

Finding a new job can be challenging in these hard times, but I absolutely wish you the best of luck in your endeavors.

1 I hate that phrase.
2 I worked in a second gerund.

The Private Life of the Gerund

"Good luck finding a new job" isn't always, or even usually, sarcastic. It's very context dependent. If the person you are writing to knows you as someone who wishes them well, and everything else you write is positive, you don't need to worry that they are going  to take it as sarcastic.
In the absence of context the easiest way to remove any possibility of misunderstanding is to add a personal subject.

I wish you the best of luck finding a new job

is very unlikely to be taken as sarcasm.

It carries the implication that the person will need luck to find a job rather than themselves being obviously employable, which is somewhat disparaging even if meant sincerely.

@PeteKirkham No it doesn't. At least, I wouldn't generally take it that way, and I suspect (though I have no proof) that only a minority of people would understand it the disparaging way without something else to suggest that's the intended meaning.

"Good luck [doing x]" is colloquially the same as "Best wishing" or "I hope [doing x] goes well" - it's generally not considered that you need to be lucky.   Job hunting can have some inherent base in luck, eg that you apply just at the right time

@DavidZ   The whole point of this Q is that ANYTHING in English can be sarcastic/disparaging so I entirely agree with Pete K that the example provided here is only fractionally better than the original, and that "is never going to be taken as sarcasm" is just plain wrong.

If you take the line that "anything can be sarcasm" then you would never say anything at all for fear of misunderstanding. Or would you? Maybe I meant that sarcastically? Or maybe only that last part?

"I wish you the best of luck finding a new job" this seems cold from my (US) perspective.  It has a "you are dismissed" vibe.

@MikeB What Pete K was saying (at least, as I understand it) is that the example here will always be taken as disparaging. My point was that, depending on the listener and the context, it will sometimes be taken as disparaging and sometimes not - I suspect more often not, but I'm not sure. I did not say "is never going to be taken as sarcasm." (Actually I don't think anyone said that.) FWIW I also think this phrase is no better than the original if your goal is to sound sincere, but that's separate from the point I was making.

I would just say ;
"Best wishes for your future endeavours."
It is not necessary the person would be doing another job, maybe he want to take a break, or maybe create his own business or write a book or take an early retirement.

Perhaps "for endeavours" is idiomatic in other dialects of English? It sounds very wooden to me. I've always heard it said as "in your (future) endeavours".

@TimR Whether this particular phrase is particularly idiomatic, or not: The idea to use a more general phrase is, I think, the proper one. "We regret that Mr/Ms X is leaving us and with him/her all the best for his/her future" or the like is unambiguous.

@TimR I actually meant that, I must have had what you call a "brain fart" and forgot to type it.

Best wishes in your endeavors. for endeavors is not grammatical.

You can just correct the text directly.  No need to keep the mistake.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.


Best of luck finding a new job.
Best of luck with your job search.

I have never heard "best of luck" used sarcastically.
P.S. In American English

Sarcastic use of 'best of luck with [that/some action or hope]' is very common indeed in the UK and Ireland. Best of luck with getting a response from Ryanair

Maybe a transatlantic difference? I've heard snarky "good luck" countless  times but never a snarky "best of luck".  Best of luck is a more formal sentiment here.  It's not something you hear out of the mouths of kids, for example, but you will hear kids say "good luck" in snark mode.

You brought up something I was thinking about, but didn't mention before. The concept of 'snark', or more exactly, what I have seen described by Americans as 'British snark'. A really bad, nasty, unattractive, even despicable thing, practically a sin against God, we gather. We don't have that word over here. I guess what is meant is good old sarcasm? So yes, a transatlantic difference.

I spent some time in England during college.  I was a plus-one once, at a rather boisterous party hosted by an Oxford student at his family's home. Nature was calling, so I asked him if he could please point me to the bathroom, and I got a very snarky "Bathroom? Do you mean the toilet?" in reply. Now, on this side of the Atlantic "bathroom" is fairly blunt—"powder room" is the middle-class euphemism—so his remark caught me by surprise. I think that must have been some "British snark".

I would have called that just plain rudeness. An unforgiveable way to behave to a guest in your home and your country. If that is 'snark', then I can see why you might very well dislike it. By the way, when I was a boy I saw a cartoon in an American science fiction magazine which showed an astronaut being shown a cabin in a spaceship. It contained a ladies' dressing table with a mirror surrounded by bulbs. A sign on the door said 'POWDER ROOM'. The other guy was saying 'The contractors misread the blueprint - this should have been a power room.'

Do you remember Archie Bunker and his 'turlet'?

@TimR Some people I know would have simply pointed you to a bathroom, sans toilet.

@SimonCrase  Such places are not up to code here :-)

I tend to avoid "luck" altogether. It's better to wish success. Luck is usually the result of random chance; success is usually the result of talent, effort, experience, etc.

@SimonCrase C. S. Lewis supposedly did this on occasion. Or just led them to the bathroom then rapidly disappeared…

@WillCrawford When I saw C.S. Lewis I thought the comment was going to be that he pointed them to the wardrobe.

@SimonCrase In the US, "I have to use the bathroom" is synonymous with relieving yourself.  You can "use the bathroom" on a bush, tree, or a wall. If you direct a (drunk) young American male to 'use the bathroom' in a room with no toilet, you may not like the result.

A corollary of the remark by JimmyJames, you can be in the bathroom and going to the bathroom simultaneously.

@JimmyJames My favourite example is from The Living Bible--1 Samuel 24:4--At the place where the road passes some sheepfolds, Saul went into a cave to go to the bathroom, but as it happened, David and his men were hiding in the cave!
